# Error when exporting customer grid to csv "cannot define correlation name 'billing_street_first_line' more than once

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, customer-grid

**EDIT:**

So I have narrowed it down to the fact that Magento does not like the JOIN when I am adding it to the collection. Is there anyway to make it so it doesnt duplicate the correlation name or whatever it is that is causing the error?

---

I've added an extra column to my customer order grid that will display the customer's street address, but when I try and export the CSV, I am getting the error "cannot define correlation name more than once". I've extended the Webtex extension "Customer Lifetime Sales" by adding a new function.

**Here is my function in the Model:**

```
public function addColumnCustomerStreetAddress($block,$after = null)
    {
        if(is_a($block, 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid')){
            $block->addColumn('street_address', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Street Address'),
                'type'      => 'text',
                'align'     => 'center',
                'index'     => 'billing_street_first_line',
                'renderer'  => 'Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Street'
            ));
            if($after)$block->addColumnOrder($this->getName(), $after);
        }
        return $block;
    }
```

**Here is my join in the Observer that grabs the customers street address:**

```
public function addAttributesToCollection($observer)
    {
        /** @var $collection  Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if(is_a($collection,'Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection'))
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('total_spent')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('total_in_cart')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('orders_count')
                ->joinAttribute('billing_street_first_line', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('last_order_date');
    }
```

**And finally, here is my renderer:**

```
class Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Street extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Now this works fine when displaying the street address in the actual grid, but when I try and export to CSV I get this error:

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:75:"You cannot define a correlation name 'at_my_shipping_street' more than once";i:1;s:2870:"#0 /opt2/sites/mySite/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, '(`at_my_shippin...', Array, NULL)
#1 /opt2/sites/mySite/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(357): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, '(`at_my_shippin...', Array, NULL)
#2 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1348): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, '(`at_my_shippin...', Array)
#3 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1315): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_joinAttributeToSelect('joinLeft', Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute), 'at_my_shipping_...', Array, 'my_shipping_str...', 'at_my_shipping_...')
#4 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(668): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_addAttributeJoin('my_shipping_str...', 'left')
#5 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/local/Webtex/CustomerLifetimeSales/Model/Observer.php(153): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->joinAttribute('my_shipping_str...', 'customer_addres...', 'default_billing', NULL, 'left')
#6 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Observer->addAttributesToCollection(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Webtex_CustomerLifetimeSales_Model_Observer), 'addAttributesTo...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('eav_collection_...', Array)
#9 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(863): Mage::dispatchEvent('eav_collection_...', Array)
#10 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(951): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#11 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(1008): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_exportIterateCollection('_exportCsvItem', Array)
#12 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(380): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->getCsvFile()
#13 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->exportCsvAction()
#14 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('exportCsv')
#15 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /opt2/sites/mySite/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /opt2/sites/mySite/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}";s:3:"url";s:83:"/mySite/index.php/myAdminArea/customer/exportCsv/key/be8bdec3e90d2a19c7d05bd23470542b/";s:11:"script_name";s:17:"/mySite/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```